# Primefaces rating component - new rating not passed to backing bean

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, rating-system

I had problems with Primefaces rating component, so I created a simple example to narrow down the problem source:

Bean:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class TestBean {
    private int rating;

    public void onrate(RateEvent rateEvent) {
        int rate = (int) rateEvent.getRating();
        this.rating = rate;
    }
    ...
}
```

Page:

```
<html ...>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="content">
                Rating = #{testBean.rating}
                <p:rating value="#{testBean.rating}">
                    <f:param name="sessionId" value="5"/>
                    <p:ajax event="rate" listener="#{testBean.onrate}"/>
                </p:rating>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

When I click any of the stars, the `rateEvent.getRating()` value is `0`. Previously I had this problem with the `@RequestScoped` bean, but the problem remains even now with the wider scope.

What might be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the correct viewscoped annotation?

Comment: @Kukeltje yes, `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`

Comment: Does it work without the template? Do you have a form?

Comment: maybe explicitly update the whole form: `<p:ajax event="rate" listener="#{testBean.onrate}" update="@form" />`?

Comment: side note: remove that useless `<h:body>` (`<ui:composition>` removes it anyway, it just slows the parse process a bit)

Comment: @Kukeltje that was the problem - I didn't place the component inside a form. Now it works. Thanks :). If you want, you can write a regular answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: See point 1 in the duplicate.